# How to save a value from an XML-MvcResult into a variable with xpath

Tags: java, spring-mvc, integration-testing, spring-test-mvc

I have an integration test, to test two rest services with content-type application/xml. The first endpoint is called by an post request to create a person, and return a revision id. This ID is generated via a sql sequence in a H2 SQL database, so this id can differ. Now I want to delete the entry  and call the second endpoint. The test should test the second endpoint.  The problem is, I need the value of the revision id from the first call.

Here is my test:

```
String revisionID;
mvc.perform(post("url/create")
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   .content(readXML("person")).accept("application/xml"))
   .andExpect(status().isCreated())
   //  here I can do some tests, but I need to store the id value
   //  I have no idea to store the node in revisionId
   .andExpect(xpath("/context/revisionId/text()").exist());

mvc.perform(delete("url/remove/revision/" + revisionId) // I need to know the id here
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Testing values or counts of nodes in this way works perfectly, but I could not find a simple solution to extract/store a value with xpath. My plan B is to use java.xml.Xpath or JAXB, but I can't belive that there is no spring way with the MockMvc framework.

I can not use json, because it is an old system that use this rest enpoints.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I used my plan B and wrote an xpath method

```
public  String getXpathValue( MvcResult xmlResult, String xpath) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, XPathExpressionException {
    String content = xmlResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    XPath xPathInstace = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    InputSource inputXML = new InputSource(new StringReader(content));
    String result = xPathInstace.evaluate(xpath, inputXML);
    return result;
}
```

and I use it like:

```
AtomicReference<Long> longAtomicReference = new AtomicReference<>();
mvc.perform(post("url/create")
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   .content(readXML("person")).accept("application/xml"))
   .andExpect(status().isCreated()) 
   .andExpect(xpath("/context/revisionId/text()").exist())
   .andDo(xmlResult -> {
        longAtomicReference.set(Long.parseLong(getXpathValue(xmlResult, "//revisionId")));
   });
Long revisionId = longAtomicReference.get();
```